# Creating Database in Blackberry phone

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, simulator

please help me out from this 
I have created a database in Blackberry phone i have also created a table inside the database but on clicking on the database on blackberry simulator it shows `UNABLE TO DISPLAY file` ,and the code I have written is

```
class CreateDatabaseSchemaScreen extends MainScreen{ 
    Database d;
    public CreateDatabaseSchemaScreen(){            


         try
         {
             URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/SQLite_Guide/"    +                    "MyEncryptedDatabase.db");
              DatabaseSecurityOptions dbso = new DatabaseSecurityOptions(true);
              d = DatabaseFactory.create(myURI,dbso);
              d= DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
              Statement s= d.createStatement("CREATE TABLE 'People' ( " +
                             "'Name' TEXT, " +
                             "'Age' INTEGER )" );
              s.prepare();
              s.execute();
              s.close();                    

              d.close();
          }
          catch ( Exception e )
          {
              System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
       } 
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean it shows "UNABLE TO DISPLAY FILE"?  Where are you clicking on the database at? Is it on your computer on the simulator? Or is it on an actual device?

Comment: i am clicking the database on simulator

Comment: I've used: http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/index.rvt  To examine the file from the simulator.  The simulator has a path on your hard drive that simulates the SD card.  So point the sql lite studio to that path.  BB doesn't have a native db viewer (at least not that I'm aware of) that you can reach on your phone.

Comment: appreciating your help its really helpful.....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database files can't be opened directly, you'll need a third party desktop tool that allows management of it. You can find a list of these tools here (generally they're free): 
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

In your BB simulator settings, you will see an option that specifies where the SDCard data is located. Once you choose a management tool, open the database in that location, and you'll be able to see if the table has been created successfully.